# Represent the value of a number by symbols

Tags: c#

Hi there i'd like to know how to display a value such as a number as a * for example 100 would = *     while 300 would = *** and 1000 would = **********

Comment: What if the number is 10, or 2? What restrictions on input values are there?

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest approach (and could very well be the fastest approach) is just to construct a new string filled with the character.

```
new String('*', number / 100)
```

---

EDIT: Actually it turns out they're not much different...

- This method: 50.71s
- Dicaste's method: 50.51s
- Jiri Leflik's method
  (adapted): 59.92s

For numbers 1-100000 though Jiri's method may be helped slightly by string interning

Answer (score 0):

My aproach.

```
private static void Main()
{
    int number = 450;

    var query = Enumerable.Repeat("*", number / 100);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(null, query));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can eaisly display a * for every hundred in a loop using Console.Write() to Console

```
public void DisplaySymbol(int nuber)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < number/100; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }
}
```